# Create a subfolder of a page with add_rewrite_rules in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get a subpage from a normal WordPress page with `add_rewrite_rule`

The page is located at `http://example.com/mypage`

The subfolder is something like `http://example.com/mypage/sub1` but can `sub2`, `sub3`or `sub4` (name is known)

The page name `mypage` (slug) is **not** known but the page id

Currently I'm stuck with this: (simplified)

```
add_action ( 'init', 'my_init' );
add_action ( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );

function my_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/(sub1|sub2|sub3|sub4)/?', 'index.php?my_page=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
function my_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = "my_page";
    return $vars;
}
```

if I goto `http://example.com/mypage` I'm on that page (obviously) but going to `mypage/sub1`end up on the homepage

Comment: What happens when you manually go to `http://example.com/index.php?my_page=sub1`? Do you get the expected `sub1` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. This is the modified `my_init` function:

```
function my_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/(sub1|sub2|sub3|sub4)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&my_page=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

please note the `pagename` variable which holds the name (slug) of the current page